# How can I reduce a frustum to the subset that passes through a portal AABB?

Tags: opengl, geometry, frustum, portals

I'm trying to implement portal based occlusion culling:

- There are sectors and portals.
- When a portal is visible, the sector it is connected to is rendered.
- The sector is made of polygons and portals.
- The sector is sealed by a portal to the next sector.
- The portal has an axis aligned bounding box.
- The view frustum has an array of mathematical planes in it. There is top, bottom, left, right, near and far.
- The view frustum planes change shape when in contact with a wall.
- When the view frustum planes are in contact with the portal's AABB, the sector get rendered.

  **Then an array of mathematical planes are added behind the portal to create a reduced view frustum.**
- Reduced frustums are made from other portals in contact with the view frustum until there are no more portals in view.

How can I perform the bolded step, where I find a new collection of frustum planes representing the portion of the original frustum that continues through the portal's AABB?